# Async/await reference-capturing of local objects is always safe or theoretically unsafe?

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency

Why `async`/`await` capturing of mutable objects is safe? For example, the code with the `async let` capturing of mutable objets immediately produce an error:

[image: See image example.]

Here full code of example:

```swift
struct User: Decodable {
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

func executeExample() {
    Task {
        var user = User(id: UUID(), name: "Taylor Swift", age: 26)
        let _ = await fetchId(for: user) // Why this code is not produce error, like code below?

        async let name = fetchName(for: user) // Reasons for this error obvious for me
        user = User(id: UUID(), name: "Taylor", age: 27)
        await print("Found \(name) name.")
    }
}


func fetchName(for user: User) async -> String {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
    print("Done fetchName")
    return user.name
}

func fetchId(for user: User) async -> UUID {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
    print("Done fetchId")
    return user.id
}
```

This piece of code `async let name = fetchName(for: user)` generates an error `Reference to captured var 'user' in concurrently-executing code` and that's ok, since I understand why it's happening.

Why doesn't this `let _ = await fetchId(for: user)` code produce errors? It seems to me that this asynchronous method could be a potential opportunity for writing unsafe code. For example, isn't there the potential concurrent access to a `user` variable from multiple asynchronous threads? And to avoid double concurrent access to the object we need to use `actor`'s.

For example: at the `let _ = await fetchId(for: user)` functions suspension point, system give a chance to another async functions(threads) to execute, so another threads(async funcs) can do write and read access at the save time to `user` variable, which will produce errors! If it didn't work that way, then we wouldn't need to use `actors` anymore! So I have a question, why the compiler does not protect potential unsafe asynchronous code `let _ = await fetchId(for: user)` by producing this error `Reference to captured var 'user' in concurrently-executing code`.

Comment: Because `let _ =` does not capture anything.

Comment: @matt can you tell me more about this direction... is`var user` code is save for accessing from another threads at `let _ = await fetchId(for: user)` functions suspension point?

Comment: That question seems meaningless to me. My advice: Don't try to reinterpret async/await in terms of "threads".

Comment: @matt ok, thanks for the answer, but can you tell me if this `var user` piece of code is thread-safe? Can I access this `var user` variable from multiple async/await functions?

Comment: How can a local variable (declared inside a function) be "accessed" from other functions? What would such code even look like? The idea makes no sense. That has nothing to do with "threads" or async/await.

Comment: Accessing local variable ` func executeExample() {
    Task {
        var user = User(id: UUID(), name: "Taylor Swift", age: 26)
        
        Task {
            let _ = await fetchId(for: user) // This code produce error!
        }
        
        let _ = await fetchId(for: user) // Why this code is not produce error, like code below?

        async let name = fetchName(for: user) // Reasons for this error obvious for me
        user = User(id: UUID(), name: "Taylor", age: 27)
        await print("Found \(name) name.")
    }
}`

Comment: @matt how I can add code into comment?

Comment: User is a struct. It is a value type. It has no mutability between function (when you pass it as a parameter, you pass a copy). There is thus no way that any of the calls you are making in `executeExample` can mutate it. The only problem is that _you_ "mutate" it between an `async let` and the corresponding `await`. The compiler cleverly points this out.

Comment: @matt For example I can create `Task` inside another `Task`, and get access to local variable and change from another Thread. But ok, maybe I'm using the `mutability` word wrong... sorry

Comment: @matt Answer from hackingwithswift: Even though it’s a struct, the user variable will be captured rather than copied and so Swift will throw up the build error “Reference to captured var 'user' in concurrently-executing code.”

Comment: "For example I can create Task inside another Task" Yes, but you don't, so that isn't what the question is about. To the extent that the space between `async let` and `await` is a Task, the compiler has caught you — and you say that you understand that. So it's hard to see what the question _is_ about at that point.

Comment: @matt The main question is "Async/await capturing of mutable objets is always safe or theoretically unsafe?"

Comment: @matt Because the "Even though it’s a struct, the user variable will be captured rather than copied and so Swift will throw up the build error “Reference to captured var 'user' in concurrently-executing code.”"

Comment: As an aside, never use `Thread.sleep` in `async`-`await`. Replace `Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)` with `try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(5))` (or in a throwing function, remove the `?`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations:

1. You asked:

   > Why async/await capturing of mutable objects is safe?

   Just to clarify, but the `User` is not a “mutable object”.

   ```swift
   struct User: Decodable {
       let id: UUID
       let name: String
       let age: Int
   }
   ```

   It is an immutable object. A “mutable object” is one with with properties that can mutate. In this case, we are dealing with a variable, e.g., where you might replace, for example, one immutable object with another.

   Note, your compiler error for your latter example says:

   > Reference to captured var 'user' in concurrently-executing code

   The problem is a captured `var`, not whether an object was mutable or not.
2. Let us consider your first example:

   > ```swift
   > let _ = await fetchId(for: user)
   > ```

   So, this is passing `fetchId` a copy of an immutable object, `User`. It also suspends execution for this current task until `fetchId` returns.

   > Why this code is not produce error, like code below?

   Because this example has `await`, which suspends execution. That prevents any other interaction with this local variable until `fetchId` returns.

   In the other example, you have an `async let` ([SE-0317](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0317-async-let.md)), however, which lets execution continue, allowing other interaction with the captured `user` variable. Again, the question is not the (im)mutability of the `User` object, but the race with respect to the `user` variable.
3. Now, elsewhere you ask:

   > The main question is “Async/await capturing of mutable objects is always safe or theoretically unsafe?”

   Let us imagine that you actually were dealing with a mutable object. In that case, it is not inherently safe unless the mutable object is `Sendable`. See WWDC 2021’s video [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133) and 2022’s [Eliminate data races using Swift Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110351/).

Comment: And do note that all of this is just what I've been saying in the comments (before I gave up).

Comment: Frankly, I hadn’t gone through your comments in any detail. Regardless, yes, it looks like we’re saying very similar things. If it bothers you, feel free to post your own answer. I don’t really care: I’m just trying to help out the OP.

Comment: @Rob wow, thanks for detailed answer. Сan you answer my additional question that I want to ask?

Comment: @Rob func executeExample() {
    Task {
        var user = User(id: UUID(), name: "Taylor Swift", age: 26)
        Task { let _ = await fetchId(for: user) } // This produce an error, and it's normal
        let _ = await fetchId(for: user) // Why this not produce an error as code above? That this code is an accomplice of a concurrent access to the same variable from multiple threads.
        async let name = fetchName(for: user) // This produce an error, and it's normal
        user = User(id: UUID(), name: "Taylor", age: 27)
        await print("Found \(name) name.")
    }
}

Comment: @Rob answer the question in code, that can be aligned via Xcode

Comment: Looks like you inserted a `Task { let _ = await fetchId(for: user) }` with a comment that says “This produce an error”. In Swift concurrency, context is important. E.g., if this was in an actor isolated method, then `Task {…}` (and the `Task {…}` therein) are both isolated to the same actor and everything would be good: no race; no error. But if you are *not* doing this in an actor-isolated context, then all bets are off, and the nested `Task` is not actor-isolated, and you introduce race on `var user`. Context is king. If you have more questions, you should probably just post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The first call to `user` has no reason to generate an error, while when you say it is "obvious" to see an error on the second call, it is not for the reason you think but because you made a mistake in the code.

The error would come if you try to capture a variable that can change from **outside** the `Task`. The variable `user` is declared ***inside*** it, so there is no concurrent code that can change its value.

The error you see is because you used `async` instead of `await`.

Just replace: `async let name = fetchName(for: user)`

With: `let name = await fetchName(for: user)`

Exactly like you did when you called `fetchId()`.

**Edit**

However, if you need to use `async let name = fetchName(for: user)`, this means that you are downloading the name *in parallel* with the rest of the code. Which means: in the meantime, the variable `user` can change. When you tried to define `user` as a `let`, the error disappeared.

But in the first call, you are using `await`, which means that the code will **not** continue until you have finished fetching the ID. So, the code is blocked until the `await` line is completed: there is no way that the variable `user` can change. That's why there's no error.

Apple explains it better [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency/): in their example, "Each photo downloads completely before the next one starts downloading". "To call an asynchronous function and let it run in parallel with code around it, write async in front of let when you define a constant, and then write await each time you use the constant."

Comment: I think you made a mistake and went in the wrong direction. <br/> > The error you see is because you used `async` instead of `await`. <br/>But it is wrong, if I change `var user` to `let user` and delete `user = User(id: UUID(), name: "Taylor", age: 27)` this code will compile successfully. Because no any no potential changes in `let user`, so is code a save! <br/>I was update my main question, please reread.

Comment: I think you made a mistake and went in the wrong direction. You said: The error you see is because you used `async` instead of `await`. But this is not the reason of the error! The real reason of error is `var user` which I must change to `let user` to fix error.

Comment: I edited my reply and tried to explain it better, I hope it helps. Basically: when using `await`, the code blocks, so there can be no changes in the variable `user` during this meantime.

Comment: thanks for the answer,  I understand that the code of  `Task block` will wait for execution of `let _ = await fetchId(for: user)` function... but at this time this func can be suspended, and another 
theoretical Threads(functionS) can get write and read access simultaneously  to this `var user`. So, `let _ = await fetchId(for: user)` is potentially unsaved code! Why you thinking that this `let _ = await fetchId(for: user)` code is thread saved?

Comment: How can another thread change a variable that was defined **inside** the `Task`??? I see that the answer was not useful, so I am surely wrong about this topic; I really want to know how that is possible. Can you please give me just **one example** (1 is enough) of any possible way to change `user` from another thread? How would another thread refer to that variable? By the way: use the words "safe" and "unsafe". "Save" means something else.

Comment: How I can add code into comment? For example I can create `Task` inside another `Task`, and get access to local variable.

Comment: func executeExample() {
    Task {
        var user = User(id: UUID(), name: "Taylor Swift", age: 26)
        
        Task {
            let _ = await fetchId(for: user) // This code produce error!
        }
        
        let _ = await fetchId(for: user) // Why this code is not produce error, like code below?

        async let name = fetchName(for: user) // Reasons for this error obvious for me
        user = User(id: UUID(), name: "Taylor", age: 27)
        await print("Found \(name) name.")
    }
}

Comment: Thanks for the example: that’s exactly how concurrency and variable scope work. It confirms my answer.

Comment: So why in the main(question) example `let _ = await fetchId(for: user)` code is not produce error? Because `user` variable is local, and we cannot get `write` and `read` access simultaneously from different `threads`?

Comment: You simply can’t access that variable from another thread. When you try to do that, like in your Task-inside-a-Task example, you get an error. So, a local variable declared inside a Task is safe to use.

Comment: "So, a local variable declared inside a Task is safe to use." Сorrect reasoning! You cool man!) thanks

Comment: Change/redact your main answer to "So, a local variable declared inside a Task is safe to use." and i accept it!